# Firebase GetValueAsync with CancellationToken C# (Unity)

Tags: c#, firebase, unity-game-engine, firebase-realtime-database

As soon as I add a cancellation token to the 'ContinueWith' callback the Task loses it's protocol of  and thus .Result generates a compile error. Is this a bug with firebase?

```
reference.Child(string.Format("friendsLeaderboard/{0}/{1}", auth.CurrentUser.UserId, seed))
        .OrderByChild("time")
        .LimitToFirst(10).GetValueAsync().ContinueWith(task => {
            if (task.IsFaulted) {

            } else if (task.IsCompleted) {
                var snapshot = task.Result;

            }
        }, token);
```

Answer (score -1):

Try using:

```
DataSnapshot snapshot = ((System.Threading.Tasks.Task<DataSnapshot>)task).Result;
```

Comment: Could you please elaborate *how* and *why* this solves the OPs issue?